# Update lambda environment variables (generated by terraform)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, terraform, environment-variables

I am running an AWS lambda and its environment variables are generated via terraform. I am getting the environment variables I need as a parameter from a dockerfile, and the values are generated by jenkins.

The issue that I'm having is that I cannot write to the .env file, and an os.putenv() call is not actually updating the lambda environment variables.

.tfvars file below

```
lambda_environment_vars = {
  "APP_PROFILE" = "dev"
  "REGION_NAME"  = "us-east-1"
  "TEST" = 1234
  "TEST2" = 9876
}
```

Trying to update

```
    os.putenv("TEST", "9000")
    os.putenv("TEST5", "800")
    os.putenv("TEST6", "900")

    for name, value in os.environ.items():
        print("{0}: {1}".format(name, value))
```

Printing values

```
    for name, value in os.environ.items():
        print("{0}: {1}".format(name, value))
```

I would expect the value of "TEST" is updated to 9000, but when the lambda is run it is still at 1234.

How can I update these via python?

Comment: How to reproduce this behavior? Here are independent pieces of code and hard to guess how it works together.

Comment: You're running the `os.putenv` code inside the Lambda function itself? Please show/explain exactly where that `os.putenv()` code is running.

Answer (score 0):

when you need to put tf variable dynamically in Jenkins pipeline, you have two options described here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#environment-variables

0. in each case your variables.tf file should look similar like this one:

```
variable "APP_PROFILE" {}
variable "REGION_NAME" {}
...
```

1. you can provide variables with terraform cli:

```
terraform apply -var 'APP_PROFILE=us-east-1' -var "REGION_NAME=us-east-1" -var ...
```

2. using environment variables like you were trying, but you need to add `TF_VAR_` prefix to each variable.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use [update_function_configuration](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.update_function_configuration) boto3 call, where you can specify new values of the variables using `Environment` argument.